# Using $vars within json schema $ref is undefined

Tags: jsonschema

While following the [documentation](https://opis.io/json-schema/2.x/variables.html#variables-and-uri-templates) for using variables in json schema I noticed the following example fails. It looks like the `number-type` doesn't get stored as a variable and cannot be read.

```json
    {
    "$id": "http://example.com/number#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "type": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": ["natural", "integer"]
        },
        "value": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/{+number-type}",
          "$vars": {
            "number-type": {"$ref": "1/type"}
          }
        }
    },
    "required": ["type", "value"],
    
    "definitions": {
      "natural": {
        "type": "integer",
        "minimum": 0
      },
      "integer": {
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }
}
```

results in

```bash
Could not find a definition for #/definitions/{+number-type}
```

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr `$vars` is not a JSON Schema keyword. It is an implementation specific extension.

The documentation you link to is not JSON Schema. It is documentation for a specific library which adds a preprocessing step to its JSON Schema processing model.

As such, this would only ever work when using that library, and would not create an interoperable or reuseable JSON Schema, if that's a consideration.

If you are using that library specifically, it sounds like a bug, and you should file an Issue in the appropriate repo. As you haven't provided any code, I can't tell what implementation you are using, so I can't be sure on that.